# how to upload a file to server from android device?

Tags: android

Is there any need to use something other than a http POST for small files? (<1mb)

With large files anyone know of an existing lib to handle them (and preferably show a progress bar in a dialog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've included apache-mime4j-0.6 and httpmime-4.0.1 to get this functionality. With those libraries you can create multipart/form-data requests and send them off with the standard HttpClient.

```
//total pseudo-code; class names are right, though
HttpPost post;
MulitpartEntity mpe;
mpe.addPart("file", new InputStreamBody() or new FileBody());
post.setEntity(mpe);
httpClient.execute(post);
```