# android - how to upload files to folder in server given the path of file in device

Tags: android, jsp, upload

How can I upload files to folder in server.

Given I have the path of the file in the sd card of the emulator and the url of the folder that contains several images.

I want to add an image to the folder in server. How can I do it?

Also I can also pass the path of the file in the sd card to a jsp file in the same server.

What should my jsp look like to save an image to a folder?

Comment: Is your problem on the client side (android) or on the server side (jsp)? Can you upload from other devices (webbrowser)? Which protocol does the server support?

Comment: I want to upload an image in the client side(sd card) to the server folder called 'images' the way ftp uploads a file. but this time I let the user select images in the sd card to be uploaded to the server. btw i can upload jsp's and images to the server via ftp

Comment: my server is tomcat and my database is mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this snippet:-

```
//total pseudo-code; class names are right, though
HttpPost post;
MulitpartEntity mpe;
mpe.addPart("file", new InputStreamBody() or new FileBody());
post.setEntity(mpe);
httpClient.execute(post);
```

You would need following libarys:-

```
apache-mime4j-0.6 
httpmime-4.0.1
```

Refer following links for more info:-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3720902

http://www.webspeaks.in/2012/08/upload-files-from-android-to-server.html

Comment: Can i reference the image file via 
`File image = request.getParameter("file");`
in my jsp page that is in the constructor `new HttpPost("jspurl");`